# Fluent API Sistema Modulado

Tags: fluent-api

Boa tarde!
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema modulado. Onde neste sistema eu tenho o módulo de cadastros, o módulo vendas, financeiro ... 
A estrutura do meu projeto está assim. Tenho uma solução, nela tenho o projeto principal onde estará tela de menu, abertura do sistema ... depois tenho um projeto chamado cadatros, e um projeto chamado vendas (cada módulo é um projeto). bom, eu gostaria que quando eu rodar o sistema, se o cliente não tiver o módulo de vendas, ele não cria as tabelas referente a vendas na base de dados (Estou desenvolvendo a base com data annotation e Fluent API - CF). Bom me deparei com o seguinte dilema: No modulo de vendas tenho a tabela pedido, que terá um relacionamento com cliente que está no módulo cadastro (As referências para acessar diretrizes de outros módulos está OK) A dúvida é .. como eu crio este relacionamento? é um relacionamento 1..N porem na model cliente não tem `public virtual ICollection<Pedido> pedidos {get;set;}`, apenas teria em Pedido `public virtual Cliente cliente {get; private set;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de muito pesquisar encontrei duas Alternativas. Caso alguém saiba de uma melhor, seria legal postar, porém darei este post como resolvido.

A Primeira alternativa é criar os Schemas de banco sem relacionamento entre as tabelas, fazer estes relacionamentos diretamente via código (não gosto muito de usar esta prática pelo fato de que se passar uma codificação despercebia nos campos para relacionamento, como mandar um Id não existente na tabela mãe, a tabela filha aceitar o registro mesmo assim, sem um controle direto do banco ...). Então seriam partes totalmente distinta das primeiras tabelas.

A Segunda forma seria importar a tabela novamente e no DBContext criar o "public virtual DBSet .... onde a classe que representa a tabela mãe seria apenas uma cópia da outra classe, aí criaria um problema, teria sempre que estar alterando as duas classes no caso de uma sofrer alteração....
Neste caso optei pela primeira alternativa que achei ser uma melhor prática neste contexto.